# suffix title with "EXPIRED" when scheduled post has reached it's published date

Tags: date, publish, scheduled-posts

I'm scheduling and displaying all my posts in the future. I'd like to somehow add some text after the post title when the publish date is reached. In effect the post will expire at the time of the publish date and therefore I need to suffix the title witH `[THIS POST IS EXPIRED]`.

Comment: Do you actually display scheduled posts _before_ their scheduled time? How do you handle that their status isn't yet set to publish in that case?

Comment: @Rarst Yes I do. I'm using the plugin  "No Future Posts (https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-future-posts/) " to publish them before the post date. Will this plugin affect what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the code below that does what I want **except** it isn't accurate to the hour. It is only accurate to the whole day, so if my post expires in the morning it still shows it as current in the afternoon.

How would this be able to be more accurate to the hour?

```
<?php if (strtotime($post->post_date) > strtotime('+1 minute')): ?>
<p>current</p>
 <?php elseif (strtotime($post->post_date) > strtotime('-999999999 days')) : ?>
<p>expired</>
<?php else : ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```